# Error 403 Forbidden

Tags: html, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

So on my website am trying new form software out and once [image: i] have installed it I cannot access it at all and I get this error:

I'm Guessing its something to do with my .htaccess file so here is the contents of that:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Also I have checked the file permissions and they are correct

any help much appreciated 
Tom

Comment: It may be a regular 404 (not found) error triggering a forbidden request (e.g. directory indexing) resulting in this page.

Comment: How would one find this out? Also any fix?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the forum is a separate application which you are trying to run inside the existing application. In which case, you might be missing rewritebase directive. something like:

```
RewriteBase /forum/
```

Have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

Comment: Is the .htaccess file inside a folder named /forum ? If so, add RewriteBase /forum/ just after RewriteEngine On

Comment: The .htaccess is in the root www.webname.co.uk/